# Imlib2 error when crosscopilation for arm target

Tags: embedded, arm, x11, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am trying to port x11 to arm processor. so i am using Imlib2 library for jpeg pictures. I have successfully cross compiled Imlib2 library with x windows to arm.My sample program also built successfully.But when i run that binary jpeg is not displaying properly.(it shows image upload error);

#

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Imlib_Image img;
    Display *dpy;
    Pixmap pix;
    Window root;
    Screen *scn;
    int width, height;
    const char *filename = NULL;

    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;
    filename = argv[1];

    img = imlib_load_image(filename);
    printf("img values %x",img);

    if (!img) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:Unable to load image\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    imlib_context_set_image(img);
    width = imlib_image_get_width();
    height = imlib_image_get_height();

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!dpy)
        return 0;
    scn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(dpy);
    root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

    pix = XCreatePixmap(dpy, root, width, height,
        DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn));
printf("caal");
    imlib_context_set_display(dpy);
    imlib_context_set_visual(DefaultVisualOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_colormap(DefaultColormapOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_drawable(pix);

    imlib_render_image_on_drawable(0, 0);

    Window w = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, root, 0, 0, width, height, 0, None, None);
    XSelectInput(dpy, w, ExposureMask); 
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    //XCopyPlane(dpy, pix, w, gc, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn));
    XFlush(dpy);




    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(dpy, w, pix);
    XClearWindow(dpy, root);

    XEvent ev;
    while (XNextEvent(dpy, &ev)) { 

        if( ev.type == Expose )
        {
            //XCopyPlane(dpy, pix, w, gc, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn));
            printf("Expose called\n");
        }
    }
    sleep(20);

    XFreePixmap(dpy, pix);
    imlib_free_image();
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;

    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <image_file>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "it shows image upload error" -- please post any error messages **verbatim**.

Comment: This message I got "error:Unable to load image"

Comment: You are trying to load the image even before you open the display, so X11 is irrelevant. Try `imlib_load_image_with_error_return`. If the error doesn't clear up the situation, I'm afraid you will have to debug imlib.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply, I got the below error so pls help me again. "Error Number 4 "IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_NO_LOADER_FOR_FILE_FORMAT""

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to call `imlib_init`.

Comment: Thank You. We are using Imlib2 Library so we cant able to call imlib_init function, if we call it tells that not declared in this scope. Please help again. What we can do?

Comment: I see. If this is a valid image file, you just might need to step through `imlib_load_image` with a debugger.